# How to get count of users who have only one between two dates in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to get count of users who have only one 1GB_DATA prize between two dates in JPA with Query annotation, but I'm getting an error.

How can I do it with JPA?

My SQL query:

```
select count(client_id) from (select client_id, count(client_id) from AV_CUSTOMER_PRIZE where prize_type ='1GB_DATA' and prize_date>'08.11.2017' and prize_date<'01.12.2017' group by client_id having count(client_id)=1);
```

My method:

```
@Query("select count(client_id) from (select client_id, count(client_id) from AV_CUSTOMER_PRIZE where prize_type ='1GB_DATA' and prize_date> :sDate and prize_date< :eDate group by " +
            "client_id having count(client_id)=1)")
    int getCount(@Param("sDate") Date startDate, @Param("eDate") Date endDate);
```

Error:

```
QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 30 [select count(client_id) from (select client_id, count(client_id) from AV_CUSTOMER_PRIZE where prize_type ='1GB_DATA' and prize_date> :sDate and prize_date< :eDate group by client_id having count(client_id)=1)]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
```

Comment: What error you got.

Comment: I updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

**1)** add `nativeQuery=true` to the `@Query` annotation. You may have problems with the date params though.

or

**2)** use only the inner query and expect a List:

```
@Query("select clientId, count(clientId) from AV_CUSTOMER_PRIZE 
        where prizeType ='1GB_DATA' and prizeTate> :sDate and prizeDate< :eDate 
        group by clientId having count(clientId)=1")
    List<Object[]> getCount(@Param("sDate") Date startDate, @Param("eDate") Date endDate);
```

then you can simply invoke .size() on the list returned.

Also remember to use entity field names instead of native db column names in that query

The **bottom line** is that you cannot use a select statement in a from clause in JPA.